# Python html web scraping on header and title

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://op1.win007.com/oddslist/1723863.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
title = soup.title.get_text()
date = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'vs'})
final_score = soup.find('div', {'class': 'score'})
half_score = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'row'})

print(date, title, final_score, half_score)

## Expected print out as follow
## 2020-03-08 23:59 星期日, 法甲, 雷恩 VS 蒙彼利埃, 5,0,2,0
```

I am a beginner in Python. I don't know why the result not same as my expected. For example:

```
date = 2020-03-08 23:59 星期日

title = '\r\n\t2019-2020 法甲         雷恩                             VS 蒙彼利埃                          百家欧指-球探体育\r\n'

final_score = [<div class="score">5</div>, <div class="score">0</div>]

half_score = [<span class="row red b">完</span>, <span class="row">(2-0)</span>]
```

Comment: You need to learn how to use BeautifulSoup to get just the value you want.  All of your Soup calls except the one to get the title are going to return HTML tags, because that's what you're asking for.  You either need to ask for just the data between the tags using the correct BS api calls, or you need to take what BS returns to you and further process it to extract just the data that you want.  I'd suggest that you work on one value at a time.  Print just that value (like `date`, which is a big string of HTML right now) and then work on the code until you get it to print just the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use CSS selectors instead of class names, because they give you more control over searching through HTML page.

Several examples:

When searching for date following code can be used:

```
date = ''.join(soup.select('div.analyhead > div.vs > div.row')[0].find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip('\n ')
```

What happens in this code?

We have following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="analyhead">
    <div class="vs">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="http://info.win007.com/cn/League.aspx?SclassID=11" target="_blank" class="LName">法甲        </a> 2020-03-08 23:59&nbsp;星期日
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="miniopen('http://zq.win007.com/ClientErr/OddsErr.aspx?ScheduleID=1723863&amp;oddsKind=2');return false;" target="_blank" class="errors">报错</a>
            <a href="1723863_3.htm" class="oldb">旧版百家</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS selector `div.analyhead > div.vs > div.row` specifies div element with class "analyhead", its direct child div with class "vs" and its direct child div with class "row".
BeautifulSoup method select() return list of found values, therefore we're taking its first element. But last div contains not only text needed, but also "a" elements, which are not needed. To exclude them we use method `find_all(text=True, recursive=False)`.
This method also return list of text values, which could be merged using string method `''.join()` and unneeded whitespaces can be stripped using `strip('\n ')`.

In similar way also final score and half score can be received:

```
final_score = ','.join(el.text for el in soup.select('#headVs > div.end > div.score'))
half_score = soup.select('#headVs > div.end > div > span.row')[1].text
```

More difficult is situation with document title. `document.title` returns "2019-2020 法甲 雷恩 VS 蒙彼利埃 百家欧指-球探体育", which should be parsed to retrieve text needed.

Alternatively you could use expression

```
title = soup.select('div.analyhead > div.vs > div.row > a')[0].text.strip(' ')
```

which returns "法甲".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. for the date, i use print(date), the result is my expected. When i put together (e.g. print(date, title, final_score, half_score)), the date was missing.